# django-polymorphic-tree serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt, django-polymorphic

I would like to serialize all the nodes in my PolymorphicMPTTModel with their corresponding fields. Following the documentation django-polymorphic and django-mptt i get this:

```
{  
   "count":1,
   "next":null,
   "previous":null,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "title":"Submenu",
         "subcategories":[  
            {  
               "title":"Plato1",
               "subcategories":[  

               ]
            },enter code here
            {  
               "title":"Plato2",
               "subcategories":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The structure is fine, but the fields of the children are missing.

#### Models:

```
class Menu(PolymorphicMPTTModel):
    parent = PolymorphicTreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', verbose_name='parent')
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200)

class SubMenu(Menu):
    titulo = models.CharField("Titulo", max_length=200,default="not defined")

class Plato(Menu):
    titulo = models.CharField("Titulo",max_length=200,default="not defined")
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    ingredientes = JSONField()
    precio = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
# Extra settings:
can_have_children = False
```

#### Serializers:

```
class PlatoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plato
        fields = ('titulo', 'descripcion', 'ingredientes', 'precio')
class SubMenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubMenu
        fields = ('titulo',)

class MenuItemModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcategories = serializers.ListSerializer(source="children",child=RecursiveField())
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('title','subcategories')
```

#### View:

```
class MenuView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Menu.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.toplevel()
    serializer_class = MenuItemModuleSerializer
```

Comment: Did you get the answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm kinda late to the party but I had the same issue and finally found a solution that is working for me.

---

As [django-rest-polymorphic](https://github.com/apirobot/django-rest-polymorphic#usage) states, you need a mapping between models and serializers:

```py
class ProjectPolymorphicSerializer(PolymorphicSerializer):
    model_serializer_mapping = {
        Menu: MenuItemModuleSerializer,
        SubMenu: SubMenuSerializer,
        Plato: PlatoSerializer
    }
```

Your RecursiveField() creates a serializer instance from its parent class. That makes all your child objects using the MenuItemModuleSerializer and thus missing child fields.

Every child needs to get mapped to its serializer using **ProjectPolymorphicSerializer**

```py
RecursiveField(to='ProjectPolymorphicSerializer')
```

Change your MenuItemModuleSerializer to this:

```py
class MenuItemModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcategories = serializers.ListSerializer(source="children", child=RecursiveField(to='ProjectPolymorphicSerializer'))
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('title','subcategories')
```